# Hiding font names on a text/font previewer

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

I am coding an online store where customers will be able to customise products any text choosing from a few hand picked fonts. I want to use a text/font preview box like on the website below:

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/cbx-jukebox/corner-store-jf/

[Creating a font preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164773/creating-a-font-preview)

My question is, if I create a text/font previewer for my website is it possible to mask the true name of the font I am using or would someone still be able to find that out by looking into the code somehow or with an addon like what font?

I thought that I could give the font files themselves different names but wasn't sure if that would work?

I looked into using cufon however my understanding is that someone could download the font file from the js.

The reason is because I have gone to a lot of time to select unique stylish fonts and I don't want to make it easy for my competitors to copy my designs by being able to easily find out what font it is

Answer (score 0):

You cannot with a client **side code** (CSS, JS). How it does hide it when the possibility is always there. Maybe it can be done with the **server-side** code like PHP GD. However, it will be very tiring work.